# Unix merging directories and sorting out duplicate file lines?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, merge, duplicates

I'm new to Unix and Bash and could use a little help with a command that will merge a number of identical directories with hundreds of text files. All file names within the directories are identical, but not all the lines in each text file.

The goal is to merge the directories, have one updated copy of each individual file with the merged content, and to remove duplicated lines.

Here's a very basic example of the directories and intended output:

```
Directory A-1
   1.txt
   2.txt
   3.txt

Directory A-2
   1.txt
   2.txt
   3.txt

End Result - Directory A
   1.txt
   2.txt
   3.txt
```

Here's the command line that I'm working with that's producing a syntax error:

```
for each $file in A-1, cat A-1/$file A-2/$file |sort|uniq > A/$file
```

If someone could provide me with the proper command syntax that will merge the directories and remove all the duplicate lines from each individual file it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in A-1/*; do 
   bn="$(basename "$f")"
   sort -u "$f" "A-2/$bn" > "A/$bn"
done
```

This assumes that for every file in A-1, there's a corresponding file in A-2 with the same name. It merges the contents of the two corresponding files, sorts them, removes duplicates, and saves the output in A/, which has to exist.

For example, assuming you start with this:

```
mkdir -p A-1 A-2 A
(
echo a 
echo b 
echo c 
) > A-1/a
(
echo b 
echo c 
echo d
) > A-2/a
```

Running the above for loop will give you an `A/a` with

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: I changed the directory names around in your example to match the existing directories and I'm receiving an error stating that there is no existing directory. I'm using cygwin and the directories are located in my c:\cgywin directory which should be the root. No typos either

Comment: All the three involved directories have to exist. You can `mkdir -p A`  to make sure the `A` directory exists.

Comment: Thanks, the utility was using a different root directory.